# Handling class attribute assignments in Polymaps

Tags: css, d3.js, javascript-objects, geojson

I'm a social science person increasingly getting into web programming for data vis work so apologies if this question is dumb. I'm working on a polymaps implementation to visualize country level data over time. I reads in json temporal data and a geojson world map and spits out a quantile chloropleth map that iterates over monthly entries. The heart of this is a country formating function that binds a colorbrewer class to the country geojson objects (see below). This works find for the animation portion. The problem is that I am using a custom d3 layer that displays the date of the data currently displayed *and* acts as a mouseover control to stop the animation and choose a date or to choose a date once the animation is through. It does this by creating an blank svg element that uses the d3.scale() function to round mouse input to an integer that matches the index of the month desired. I've front loaded all the other calculations on load so that the only thing that happens at mouse over is the change of svg class (this is basically the same as Tom Carden's wealth of nations implementation on Bostock's d3 page [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/)). Unfortunately, this still overloads the browser pretty quickly. Is there another way to do this that I'm totally missing? I admit im new to geojson so maybe some way to construct an array of classes with in the class attribute of the geojson object?  Thanks a ton of any help.

```
            function foo(local, geojson){
                for(var x=0;x<geojson.length;x++){
                    var n = geojson[x].data.properties.name;
                    n$(geojson[x].element)
                        .attr("class", geojson[x].data.formats[local])
                        .add("svg:title");
                }
            }
```

EDIT: I'm adding the full script below.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="scripts/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/polymaps.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/nns.js"></script>

<script>
    //Polymaps namespace
    var po = org.polymaps;

    //Chart dimensions
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};
    var w = 960 - margin.right;
    var h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Create the map object, add it to #map div
    var map = po.map()
        .container(d3.select("#map").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",h +margin.top + margin.bottom).node())
        .center({lat: 28, lon: 0})
        .zoom(1.85)
        .zoomRange([1.5, 4.5])
        .add(po.interact());

    // Add the CloudMade image tiles as a base layer…
    map.add(po.image()
        .url(po.url("http://{S}tile.cloudmade.com"
        + "/1a1b06b230af4efdbb989ea99e9841af" // http://cloudmade.com/register
        + "/20760/256/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png")
        .hosts(["a.", "b.", "c.", ""])));

    //Import contribution data
    d3.json("assets/contributionsTCC1990-1991.json", function(data){
        //find length of json data object and loop over it at interval
        var dataLength = Object.keys(data).length;

        //Create date  key/value array using construtor
        function date_array_constructor() {
            var dateArray = {};
                for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                    var d = i + 1;
                    dateArray[d] =  data[i].date;
                }
            return dateArray;
        }
        var dateArray = date_array_constructor();

        // Insert  date label/control layer and add SVG elements that take on attributes determined by load function
        var labelLayer = d3.select("#map svg").insert("svg:g");
        map.add(po.geoJson()
            .url("assets/world.json")
            .tile(false)
            .zoom(3)
            .on("load", load));
        map.container().setAttribute("class", "Blues");
        map.add(po.compass()
            .pan("none"));

        function find_max(data, dataLength) {
            var max = 0;
            for(var i in data) {
                if(data[i] > max) {
                    max = data[i] + 1;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        function max_array_constructor(data, dataLength) {
            var maxArray = {};
            for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++) {
                var d = i+1;
                maxArray[d] = find_max(data[i].contributions);
            }
            return maxArray;
        }
        var maxArray = max_array_constructor(data, dataLength);

        function contribution_array_constructor(data, dataLength, tccName, feature) {
            var contributions = {};
            //iterate over date entries
            for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++) {
                //contribution iterator
                contributions[i+1] = 0;
                for(x in data[i].contributions){
                    if(x == tccName) {
                        contributions[i+1] = data[i].contributions[x];
                    }
                }
            }
            return contributions;
        }


        function format_array_constructor(data, dataLength, maxArray, feature) {
            var formats = {};
            // console.log(feature.data.contributions);
            //iterate over date entries
            for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++) {
                var percentile = feature.data.contributions[i+1] / maxArray[i+1];
                if(percentile != 0){
                    var v = "q" + ((~~(percentile*7)) + 2) + "-" + 9;
                }else{
                    var v = "countries";
                }
                formats[i+1] = v;
            }
            return formats;
        }


        ///////////////////////////////
        //load function
        ///////////////////////////////
        function load(e) {
            //Bind geojson and json
            var geojson = e.features;
            console.log(geojson);
            geojson.dates = dateArray;
            for(var x = 0; x < geojson.length; x++) {
                // var tccID = geojson[x].data.id;
                var tccName = geojson[x].data.properties.name;
                geojson[x].data.contributions = contribution_array_constructor(data, dataLength, tccName, geojson[x]);
                geojson[x].data.formats = format_array_constructor(data, dataLength, maxArray, geojson[x]);
            }


            //Insert date label
            var dateLabel = labelLayer.append("text")
                .attr("class", "date label")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("x", w-670)
                .attr("y", h )
                .text(dateArray[1]);

            //Add interactive overlay for date label
            var box = dateLabel.node().getBBox();

            var overlay = labelLayer.append("rect")
                .attr("class", "overlay")
                .attr("x", box.x)
                .attr("y", box.y)
                .attr("opacity",0)
                .attr("width", box.width)
                .attr("height", box.height)
                .on("mouseover",enable_interaction);


            function country_class_constructor(local, geojson){
                for(var x=0;x<geojson.length;x++){
                    var n = geojson[x].data.properties.name;
                    n$(geojson[x].element)
                        .attr("class", geojson[x].data.formats[local])
                        .add("svg:title");
                }
            }

            function foo(local, geojson){
                for(var x=0;x<geojson.length;x++){
                    var n = geojson[x].data.properties.name;
                    n$(geojson[x].element)
                        .attr("class", geojson[x].data.formats[local])
                        .add("svg:title");
                }
            }

            //incrementor function
            function incrementor(local, geojson, dateArray) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    //set date label to current iteration
                    d3.transition(dateLabel).text(dateArray[local]);
                    //construct country classes
                    country_class_constructor(local, geojson);
                    // console.log(geojson);
                }, 500*local);
            }

            ///////////////////////////////
            //Increment on load
            ///////////////////////////////
            country_class_constructor(1, geojson)
            for(var i=1; i< dataLength; i++) {
                //Set incrementer as local variable
                var local = i+1;
                var timer = incrementor(local, geojson, dateArray);
            }


            ///////////////////////////////
            //interaction element
            ///////////////////////////////
            function enable_interaction(){
                var dateScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1,Object.keys(dateArray).length])
                    .range([box.x + 10, box.x + box.width - 10])
                    .clamp(true);

            timer = null;


                overlay
                    .on("mouseover", mouse_over)
                    .on("mouseout",mouse_out)
                    .on("mousemove",mouse_move)
                    .on("touchmove",mouse_move);

                function mouse_over() {
                    dateLabel.classed("active", true);
                }

                function mouse_out() {
                    dateLabel.classed("active", false);
                }

                function mouse_move() {
                    update_map(dateScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),data);
                    // displayYear(dateScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]));
                }

                function update_map(userInput) {
                    var date = Math.floor(userInput);
                    d3.transition(dateLabel).text(dateArray[date]);
                    // console.log(date);
                    // country_class_constructor(date, geojson);
                    foo(date, geojson);
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Edit 2: I forgot to add the JSON format. See below for two months of data:

```
[
{"date":"11/90",
 "contributions":{
    "Algeria":7,
    "Argentina":39,
    "Australia":41,
    "Austria":967,
    "Bangladesh":5,
    "Belgium":4,
    "Brazil":27,
    "Canada":1002,
    "Chile":7,
    "China":5,
    "Colombia":12,
    "Czech Republic":6,
    "Denmark":374,
    "Ecuador":21,
    "Fiji":719,
    "Finland":992,
    "France":525,
    "Germany":13,
    "Ghana":892,
    "Hungary":15,
    "India":40,
    "Indonesia":5,
    "Ireland":814,
    "Italy":79,
    "Jordan":6,
    "Kenya":7,
    "Malaysia":15,
    "Nepal":851,
    "Netherlands":15,
    "New Zealand":22,
    "Nigeria":2,
    "Norway":924,
    "Poland":165,
    "Republic of the Congo":6,
    "Russia":35,
    "Senegal":4,
    "Serbia":17,
    "Spain":63,
    "Sweden":738,
    "Switzerland":5,
    "Turkey":2,
    "United Kingdom":769,
    "United States":33,
    "Uruguay":10,
    "Venezuela":23,
    "Zambia":6
 }
},
{"date":"12/90",
 "contributions":{
    "Algeria":7,
    "Argentina":39,
    "Australia":41,
    "Austria":967,
    "Bangladesh":5,
    "Belgium":4,
    "Brazil":27,
    "Canada":1002,
    "Chile":7,
    "China":5,
    "Colombia":12,
    "Czech Republic":6,
    "Denmark":374,
    "Ecuador":21,
    "Fiji":719,
    "Finland":992,
    "France":525,
    "Germany":13,
    "Ghana":892,
    "Hungary":15,
    "India":40,
    "Indonesia":5,
    "Ireland":814,
    "Italy":79,
    "Jordan":6,
    "Kenya":7,
    "Malaysia":15,
    "Nepal":851,
    "Netherlands":15,
    "New Zealand":22,
    "Nigeria":2,
    "Norway":924,
    "Poland":165,
    "Republic of the Congo":6,
    "Russia":35,
    "Senegal":4,
    "Serbia":17,
    "Spain":63,
    "Sweden":738,
    "Switzerland":5,
    "Turkey":2,
    "United Kingdom":769,
    "United States":33,
    "Uruguay":10,
    "Venezuela":23,
    "Zambia":6
 }
}
```

]

Comment: Is that visualisation live somewhere? It's hard to understand what's going on without seeing it.

Comment: It's running local right now. Basically its a chloropleth of peacekeeping contributions with temporal variation. The percentile of a country's monthly contribution determines the quantile category which determines the color brewer associated css class. These contributions change each month and so the map animates over the month to show the shifting distribution of troop contributions. The big date label does double duty as a control for what month is being viewed. The full data spread is 177 geojson elements and 266 months of country level data.

Comment: It sounds like the bottleneck may be simply the redrawing of the elements and not the data processing. I can't really give you any more information without having seen it though -- sounds like a big project and it could be all sorts of things. If you're not comfortable with making the code public, feel free to contact me privately.

Comment: I just didnt want to force anyone to read through all my crappy uncleaned code but I'll put it below.  I think you're right on the redrawing bottleneck. Is there a way to change classes without rerendering. Kind a side question I guess is is there also a way to set delay triggers with out the setTimeout function? Once I got this kink worked out I was going to experiment with using d3.transition function but I'm not at all sure that will work.

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need your JSON as well to actually try it... Maybe you could put everything in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I've added a JSON sample of 2 months but need to do some work on it to get it to work in jsfiddle. I just ran across that the other day actually so this is a good time to practice at it.

Comment: I've got it hosted [here](http://www.owlandthistlegeneral.com/tcc-visulaization-stripped/index.html). Since there are external JSON files and I'm not entirely sure how to handle those with fiddle, this is easier. I've stripped out the interaction and extended the data it handles up to 2000 and even with out interaction there's what looks like a rendering bottleneck. I'm sure this is some dumb noob mistake.

Comment: I've had a look at it, but it's complex enough that I don't really have an idea where the issue lies. To debug this, I would start by changing the time between the transitions and watching the CPU usage, i.e. how long does it take for a transition to "settle" and play around with the code and see how that time changes.

Comment: I was in the process of trying that when you replied. It seems that the DOM tree is adding about 3000 entries per year so that it starts off with about 1000 and ends with almost 30,000 which makes me think that it has something to do with the way that polymaps caches data. Does that sound right?

Comment: It certainly shouldn't be necessary to add new data from what I've seen, only update the existing data. I'm not familiar enough with Polymaps to help here though.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging, it turns out that the nns.js library was causing me problems. Each iteration of the animation was creating a new set of DOM objects which started to max out the browser at 25,000. The solution was to use nss to create the initial state and then using the following function to change the class of each svg element.

```
function country_class_constructor(local, geojson){
                for(var x=0;x<geojson.length;x++){
                    var n = geojson[x].data.properties.name;
                    element = document.getElementById(n);
                    element.className["animVal"] = geojson[x].data.formats[local];
                    element.className["baseVal"] = geojson[x].data.formats[local];
}
```